postfix: rewrite all emails expect those from two defined domains
I am searching and testing for hours, but I couldn't find a solution so far :(
we have a postfix and rewrite every email to a special sender and relay it to an o365 server.
at the moment it is like this:
main.cf:
sender_canonical_classes = envelope_sender, header_sender
sender_canonical_maps =  regexp:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical_maps

/etc/postfix/sender_canonical_maps:
/.*/    project-mail01@projectdomain.xxx

now we want to change this, every mail should be rewritten besides mails from two special domains.
the idea was the following:
/etc/postfix/sender_canonical_maps:
/^.*@project\.com$/        $0
/^.*@projectdomain\.xxx$/   $0
/.*/    project-mail01@projectdomain.xxx

but here I get the following error in /var/log/mail.log
warning: regexp map /etc/postfix/sender_canonical_maps, line 1: out-of-range replacement index "0"
warning: regexp map /etc/postfix/sender_canonical_maps, line 1: bad replacement syntax: skipping this rule
warning: regexp map /etc/postfix/sender_canonical_maps, line 2: out-of-range replacement index "0"
warning: regexp map /etc/postfix/sender_canonical_maps, line 2: bad replacement syntax: skipping this rule

Can anybody point me in the right direction, on how to solve that problem with the two domains?
cheers and have a great day!
Ringo

Matched patterns start with $1 not $0.
